# OpenLayers3 - scale within zoomlevel

Tags: scale, openlayers-3

Is there a way within ol3 to scale up/down the tiles within a given zoomlevel?

What I would like to achieve:
Some maps are really hard to read on small devices - especially if you have a little greater viewing distance. So it could be helpful to be able to apply a moderate scale (e.g. 2) so that a tile of 256x256 would be rendered at 512x512 (more ore less what ol3 is doing if we allow for higher zoom then our source provides).

A made a simple example that scales the container - see at http://wellenvogel.github.io/ol3-scaletest/ - but this has great disadvantages:

- it would break ol3 pointer coordinate detection
- it would scale all vector layers - not very usefull

So I'm wondering if there is any chance to achieve this - e.g. by setting different resolutions at the view/tilegrid/source.